# I need help using scp on SSH, "connections timed out" I am using 2 windows 10 computers for this file transfer

Tags: ssh, windows-10, scp

So ive been practicing using SSH and im trying to copy a file from a remote computer to my local computer however, This is my cmd:

USER2@WINDOWS C:\Users\USER2>scp FILE1.txt USER1@192.168.1.140:/Users/USER1/Desktop

ssh: connect to host 192.168.1.140 port 22: Connection timed out

Am I typing this thing wrong or is there something i am mising?

Comment: can you ping that ip-address

Comment: Yes i can ping it, ive also checked that OpenSSH server is running on that computer using services.msc

Answer (score 0):

Found out what the issue was, the OpenSSH server on my local computer was not on, once U turned it on by going to services.msc < OpenSSH server, click on it, and a window shows up, you will see a start button, once clicked, the command worked like a charm.